# JavaScript scope discrepancy between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, scope

I wrote a jQuery plugin to force numerical values in input fields, and it works fine in Chrome and Safari but not in Firefox. I have posted a piece of the script below, and in Firefox it fails on the first line, with the error `ReferenceError: setDefault is not defined`. Why wouldn't this line work in Firefox?

[Link to full script](https://bitbucket.org/stconrad/jquery-numeric/src/60d225573227881dd867dda9de4d073d9c7725ac/jquery-numeric.js?at=master)

```
isDollar = setDefault(options.isDollar, isDollar);
isReal = setDefault(options.isReal, isReal);
allowDecimal = setDefault(options.allowDecimal, allowDecimal);
allowNegative = setDefault(options.allowNegative, allowNegative);
maxDigits = setDefault(options.maxDigits, maxDigits);

function setDefault(myVar, defaultVal){
    if(typeof myVar === "undefined") myVar = defaultVal;
    return myVar;
}
```

Comment: Could you put the full version of your script? Your example tells nothing :)

Comment: sure, it's actually on bitbucket, a bit long so I'll probably just link to that https://bitbucket.org/stconrad/jquery-numeric/src/60d225573227881dd867dda9de4d073d9c7725ac/jquery-numeric.js?at=master

Comment: Very nice catch! You can put this script as an example: `if(true){    test();function test(){console.log("Das ist fantastisch");}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems Firefox has a much more strict interpretation of ECMA standards. What I left out of the code snippet is that the whole thing is inside of an `if` block. Apparently, in that case, JavaScript executed in Firefox will not be able to call `setDefault` before it is declared. Interesting that this code will work in other browsers but explode in Firefox. Lesson learned.